# Why are subsequent queries so much slower?

Tags: jpa, oracle11g, ejb, datasource, jboss7.x

I'm trying to sort out a very weird behavior.

I'm working with:

- `JBoss AS 7.1.1`
- `EJB 3.0`
- `JPA`
- `XA DataSource`
- `Oracle 11g`

In one of the systems fuctionalitites, the user can see the status of each `Store`. For each `Store` I fire a query, to sum up all the files that have been processed. The query is something like this:

```
 SELECT 
    SUM(CASE file.type
            WHEN 'TYPE_1' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END) 
    , 
    SUM(CASE file.type
            WHEN 'TYPE_2' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END) 
    , 
    SUM(CASE file.type
            WHEN 'TYPE_3' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END) 
 FROM 
    File file
 WHERE 
    file.type IN ('TYPE_1', 'TYPE_2', 'TYPE_3') 
    AND file.status = 'RECEIVED' 
    AND file.store.id = :storeId
```

The thing is, the user can select which of the stores he wants to check, and that's where things get weird.

When I check the first store, the result comes blazing fast, but all subsequent queries take significantly more time. Let me exemplify:

1. User checks store 15 (Blazing fast result) - About 200 ms
2. User checks store 2  (Very slow result)    - About 8000 ms

Now pay attention to this part, it's very important.

1. User logs out, and logs in again.
2. User checks store 2 (the one that took 8000ms), and now the result is blazing fast.

This is very odd, the same store that took a while before, is now loading pretty fast.
Whenever I try the queries on `SQLDeveloper` the results come pretty fast as well.

I annotated my `EJB` with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)` but I didn't get any difference on the execution time.

I created a standalone project to run the queries using `JDBC` and the result was fast again, which leaves me thinking it may be some configuration on my `DataSource`, `persistence.xml` or anything like that.

Does anyone have any clues why this happens?

Comment: How do you manage sessions, transactions?

Comment: how about logging the JDBC calls and see if something else other than just your query is getting executed?

Comment: @Olaf they are all managed by the container, I inject an instance of the `EntityManager`

Comment: @OldProgrammer , I did that, it only runs the queries that I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

few things :

1. when the user checks store2 in the second time , the oracle optimizer is probably using it's "cache" , and therefore it is blazing fast.
2. how much File records does store2 has ? try to perform a group by sentence to see if this File table needs special statistics , if for example the store2 has dramaticly more File records than other stores then try to perform this method :

`begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'file' , estimate_percent=>100);
    end;`

this will ensure the table's statistics are accurate.

1. you can optimize the query , you don't have to perform 3 times "sum" , you can do something like this :

   `select f.type , count(*)
   from File f
   where f.store.id = :storeId
   and f.type IN ('TYPE_1', 'TYPE_2', 'TYPE_3') 
   group by f.type`

Comment: the weird thing is that the fastest search is actually the first one, not the others. If it were backwards I would think of cache immediately, but I have never seen them behave like this, in this order. I'll give your suggestions a try, though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you may run in a cardinality feedback problem; just look in this blog;

http://orcasoracle.squarespace.com/oracle-rdbms/2012/12/18/when-a-query-runs-slower-on-second-execution-a-possible-side.html

/KR

Comment: This was the answer to subsequent slow query result for a coworker.